# Gnuplot boxplots, control the extend of whiskers up to a target percentile

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I am using gnuplot boxplots to plot some statistical data. I want to change the extend of whiskers for my boxplots to extend up to a specified percentile, say 99th. According to documentation it seems to be possible.

Gnuplot documentation ([on page 45](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf)) states:

> A box is drawn around the region between the first and third
>   quartiles, with a horizontal line at the median value. Whiskers extend
>   from the box to user-specified limits.

However, it is not stated how to do it. Documentation mentions the width of the whiskers but not their extend.

My two questions are:
Q1: How to control the extend of the whiskers
Q2: Do I need to compute my target percentiles (e.g., 99th) myself and then set it or gnuplot can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the documentation of `set style boxplot` correctly, you should use

```
set style boxplot fraction 0.99
```

That extends the whiskers "symmetrically from the median value until it encompasses the requested fration of the data set. Here gain each whisker is constrained to end at a point in the data set" (from documentation).